# Make function accept 0-9 and X

Tags: python, function, input

I'm making a function that will keep asking for a new input until it receives either numbers 0-8 or 'X'. So far I made this, but it doesn't work. I know why it doesn't work, but don't know how to make it work.

```
def get_computer_choice_result(computer_square_choice):
    print('What is hidden beneath square', computer_square_choice, '? (0 - 8 -> number of surrounding mines or X)')
    field_content = input()
    while not (ord(field_content) > ord('0') and ord(field_content) < ord('8')) or field_content != 'X':
        field_content = input('Invalid input.Please enter either 0 - 8 -> number of surrounding mines, or X -> a mine.')
    return field_content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are perfect for your needs:

```
import re

def get_computer_choice_result(computer_square_choice): 
    print('What is hidden beneath square', computer_square_choice, '? (0 - 8 -> number of surrounding mines or X)') 
    field_content = input() 
    while not re.match(r"([0-8]|X)$", field_content):
        field_content = input('Invalid input.Please enter either 0 - 8 -> number of surrounding mines, or X -> a mine.') 
    return field_content
```

Edit:
Also, your condition could work but it is wrong. It should be the following:

```
while not (ord(field_content) >= ord('0') and ord(field_content) <= ord('8')) and field_content != 'X':
```